# Add a magic link to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, magic-links

I would like to have this magic link:

`[help/editing]` or `[help/markdown]` or `[markdown]` or `[editing]` or `[help/formatting]` or `[formatting]` or `[markdown-formatting]`

with the text "editing help" or "how to edit", redirecting to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: Well, it's really more "Markdown help" than "editing help" or "how to edit" (despite the URL).  So I would rather it be something like `[markdown]`.

Comment: @RyanM, yes, I meant something like Markdown too. But why are these URLs so confusing? It's more of a 'formatting help' page.

Comment: *"But why are these URLs so confusing?"* - I'm sure it seemed a good idea at the time, who knows how many years ago it was first created. I second 'formatting help', since it applies to both creating and editing content but the page offers only help for formatting, a subset of content creation. help/formatting seems the most logical to me. I am second guessing why we would need the shortcut though. The site should bring people to that url, not commentators.

Comment: @Gimby, what do you mean by "The site should bring people to that url, not commentators."?

Comment: They mean that SO should have clear, well presented, guidance on how to use itself, without a user having to intervene and explain it for SO. A well designed system should give you everything you need to know to use it correctly. A poorly designed system requires some 3rd party to explain how to use it. Of course if everything was well designed, no one would ever have a reason to ask on SO.

Comment: A shortcut to the list of shortcuts. That's so meta it could only be discussed on Meta.

Comment: I don't know a single magic link. Should I be ashamed?

Comment: @PoulBak No, I've been noodling around on here for 9 years and this is the first time I've ever seen the editing help. And I still have no idea what the heck a "Community Wiki" is or why anybody would want one.

Comment: Complete Support...! And I also *really* miss a Magic Link for Tag Wikis, ... but was [already asked](/q/363729), ... and 4 years later still not implemented...

Comment: Is there a list of magic links? I know about '[ask]' and '[mcve]'. Are there more?

Comment: @TDG, yes: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188238/1056862.

Answer (score 44):

It's not quite as convenient as you want, but a little known feature is that you can use domain-relative links that start with a slash in your markdown. `[markdown formatting documentation](/editing-help)` gets rendered as a properly working link: [markdown formatting documentation](/editing-help). At least you don't have to type out the whole "https://stackoverflow.com".

I'd like a magic link shortcut as well, but in the meantime, maybe this tip will result in a bit less typing for you.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried `[help/editing-help]` before posting this question, but it didn't render as a link. I thought that the "editing-help" page is in the "help" folder. I was so vexed up searching for an MSE post containing a list of all the "magic links" I was. Didn't know that such relative path links work too!

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder: This isn't magic at all, this is the normal `[text](url)` markdown.  Without a `(url)` part, yeah you just get [text].  The only trick here is using a relative URL.  You do of course also have to use the right path.